# $A$ is open as a subset of $Y$ $\Leftrightarrow$ it is the intersection with $Y$ of a set which is open in $X$

Tags: metric-spaces

**The problem:**

Let $Y$ be a subspace of a metric space $X$, and let $A$ be a subset of the metric space $Y$. Show that $A$ is open as a subset of $Y$ $\Leftrightarrow$ it is the intersection with $Y$ of a set which is open in $X$.

**My work so far:**

$\Leftarrow$
If $A$ is the intersection with $Y$ of a set which is open in $X$, then given any $x\in A$ there exists $r>0$ such that $S_r(x)\subseteq A$, let $Q=S_r(x) \cap Y$ then for all $q\in Q$, $d(x,q)<r$ thus $Q$ is an open sphere in $Y$.

$\Rightarrow$ If $A$ is open as a subset of $Y$ then for $x\in A$ there is $r>0$ such that $S_r(x)\subseteq Y$. Suppose there exists $z\in X$ such that $d(x,z)<r$, $z\notin Y$, ...

**My question:**

Does this argument make sense, and how can I complete the proof of $\Rightarrow$? I find the notion of "an intersection with $Y$ of a set which is open in $X$" confusing since I'm not sure how to construct this set.

[For reference, this is Problem 10-7 of *Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis* by G.F. Simmons.]

Comment: Basically what you're trying to show is that the topology induced by the metric $d$ restricted to $A$ is the same as the subspace topology on $A$. Since any open set in a metric space can be written as the union of open balls, it suffices to only consider open balls - that should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument for the direction $\Leftarrow$ is correct. So let's do the reverse direction.

$\Rightarrow$ Suppose $A$ is an open subset of $Y$. Then, for every $x\in A$, 
one can find $r_{x}>0$ such that 
$$
\{y\in Y: d(y, x)<r_{x}\}\subset A
$$
As a result, 
$$
A=\bigcup_{x\in A} \{y\in Y: d(y, x)<r_{x}\}
$$
Now let $O=\displaystyle\bigcup_{x\in A} \{y\in X: d(y, x)<r_{x}\}$. Then $O$ is open in $X$, and satisfies $A=Y\cap O$.